# Virtual Terminal For Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, virtual-terminal

I'm new to ubuntu and unix-based systems in general so i wanted to ask what the best terminal emulator would be to connect to a mid-1980's ibm 5150 over a d25 serial cable?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. the IBM is running PC-DOS 3.30